# How to create index with custom type field mapping?

Tags: elasticsearch

*Elasticsearch 6.2.4*

I want to create an index with [custom type field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/removal-of-types.html#_custom_type_field) mapping.

Tried to create the index using the example in the doc:

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -XPUT 'localhost:9200/twitter?pretty' -d'
{
  "mappings": {
    "user": {
      "properties": {
        "name": { "type": "text" },
        "user_name": { "type": "keyword" },
        "email": { "type": "keyword" }
      }
    },
    "tweet": {
      "properties": {
        "content": { "type": "text" },
        "user_name": { "type": "keyword" },
        "tweeted_at": { "type": "date" }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

And got an error:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "Rejecting mapping update to [twitter] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [tweet, user]"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason" : "Rejecting mapping update to [twitter] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [tweet, user]"
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

Comment: You cannot create two different types in the same index, you need to create two different indexes. more info here: https://www.elastic.co/blog/great-mapping-refactoring

Comment: @Val are you saying the example in the doc is wrong? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/removal-of-types.html#_custom_type_field

Comment: Have you read the full page? This is the documentation that explains why your example doesn't work.

Comment: @Val yes, I got it. The right example is below the wrong one in the doc.